# Validating formik field containing array of objects using Yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, formik, yup

Sample code: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-bose-4qhoh?file=/src/App.tsx

I'm attempting to build a form that will accept a `Criteria` array of `Criterion` objects that are of a specific type:

```
export interface Criterion {
  field: string,
  op: string,
  values: []
}

export interface Configuration {
  title: string,
  description: string,
  criteria: Criterion[],
}
```

So the `Configuration` object can have multiple `Criterion` used to define a web API query.
I've got this far, but while `yup` correctly validates the array, when it gets to formik it seems to treat it as a string again, even though the types are defined (I *think*) correctly.

Here's an example of what I'm seeing, if you submit the form using an array like this as the `criteria` value:

```
[
  {
    "field": "createdOn",
    "op": "Equal",
    "values": [
      "2020-01-01"
    ]
  }
]
```

the formik value shows:

```
 "criteria": "[\n    {\n      \"field\": \"createdOn\",\n      \"op\": \"Equal\",\n      \"values\": [\n        \"2020-01-01\"\n      ]\n    }\n  ]"
```

Is there a way to get formik to treat this as an array of javascript objects instead of a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse the value of criteria to JSON first (because it is a string from the textarea, not an object), then reassign it like this:

```
            let temp = { ...values };
            temp.criteria = JSON.parse(values.criteria);
```

Sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-northcutt-f0d8k?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Thanks @Viet but that throws a TS error: `Argument of type 'Criterion[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2345)` -- it seems like typescript thinks the escaped string is a valid object?

Comment: ok, need to convert to string here:           temp.criteria = JSON.parse(values.criteria.toString());